# Make hat tooltip (and everywhere) more clear

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Currently the hat count shows the count of **different** hats (because one hat can be earned more then once), but even the tooltip doesn't explain that:

> [image]

My request is to add the word "different" (or a more suitable word in this context) for more clearer text.

Comment: "unique" seem more fitting.

Comment: I use the word 'distinct'.

Comment: `select count(*) from UserHats where UserId = ? group by HatTypeId;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TheSharpieOne suggested, an appropriate tooltip would be:

> x unique hats

where "x" is the number shown on the blue hat.